# SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult for EMR

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I tried running my Spark application from EMR, which right now is just the pi calculation in the tutorial doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-application.html

I uploaded that .py file into s3 and asked the EMR to add a step, with the .py file as the JAR.

It always ends up erroring with following message

```
22/12/20 00:52:24 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:514) ~[spark-yarn_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:278) ~[spark-yarn_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:929) ~[spark-yarn_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:928) ~[spark-yarn_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.2.1-amzn-8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:928) ~[spark-yarn_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala) ~[spark-yarn_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkUserAppException: User application exited with 1
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:111) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:742) ~[spark-yarn_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-0]
22/12/20 00:52:24 INFO ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory hdfs://ip-10-0-7-133.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1671497445713_0001
22/12/20 00:52:25 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

I'm a total noob to EMR and have no idea what this error message indicates, since nothing is pointing out anything about my code.

Could someone tell me how to look for what is actually wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the controller logs, and check if the spark-submit command is correct.